# Compile Excel Spreadsheet from Outlook Message

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, automation

I would like to know if it is possible to compile an Excel Spreadsheet from an email message.
I receive several email messages every day with the same format (the report of a procedure) and I would auto-compile my Excel table, without boring copy-paste actions.

Here an example:

Email:

```
Procedure 123456 of day 01/06/2014 closed by operator Mike in date 05/06/2014 at 20:20.30
```

Excel:

```
Procedure   OrigDate    CloseDate             Operator
----------  ----------  --------------------  ----------  
123456      01/06/2014  05/06/2014 20:20.30   Mike
```

Plese let me know if this is possible and how to do this!

Thanks!

Comment: You're more likely to get detailed responses if you show the effort you've put into this so far. [Edit] your question with information about what you've researched, tried, and where you got stuck. Also, including the versions of Excel and Outlook is helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use VBA to write a macro to parse the e-mail, create an Excel Workbook and copy the text from one to the other. To get to VBA in Outlook just press Alt-F11, you'll have to write a Sub to do the import. You'd still need to run the macro having opened your e-mail so it wouldn't be fully automated. It may be possible to create a rule based upon the subject if you want to fully automate it.